# create new instance from same project in C#

Tags: c#, installation, project

I have a project in c# which is represent a Ground Station for Aircraft.
I need functionality that when I click on save test, then there is a new project same as the Ground station will be created.

simply just like the visual studio project there is a button to create new project, which is same as visual project.

in other word, I need to create new project from same project with customized configuration.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean how to create an exact copy of the project you're currently working on?

If so, I'm not sure there's an automated way to accomplish this, but you can just go into Documents\Visual Studio %YourYear%\Projects\%YourProject%, where you replace both of the %-delimited values with your local values. Then, just copy your entire project folder, give it a new name, and open the solution therein. You'll be able to edit it as you see fit without changing the original version.

However, I think you'd be better off using some sort of version control system, like Git or Subversion. With either of these, you can create branches off your master version. You can effect whatever changes you like with these branches without affecting any changes to the original master. If you decide the changes you've made on any branch are worth keeping, you can merge some or all of them with the master and create a new master version.